# Should I use double quotes? (Shell Script)

Tags: shell, csh

I have a block of C Shell script like this:

```
set scriptname="`basename $0`"
set lockfile=/var/run/$scriptname.pid
set overridefile=/var/tmp/$scriptname.override
set logdir=/var/log/myapp

umask 022

set hostname=`/bin/hostname`

if (-e $overridefile) then
   ...
   exit 1
endif

if (-r $lockfile) then
   ...
endif

...

/bin/rm -f $lockfile
exit 0
```

I am not sure about the line

```
set scriptname="`basename $0`"
```

I want to get the name of the current script. Do I need the double quotes here? Is this the correct way to do so?

Comment: `csh` is (arguably) fine for interactive use, but it should never be used in a script.  Instead of using double quotes, you should use a different shell.

Comment: If the script's filename doesn't contain any whitespace characters (e.g., space, tab, etc.), you _should_ get the script's filename back, including extension.  The double quotes are redundant in that case.  However, regardless of which shell you're using, you will run into troubles using `basename` if the script's name has whitespace characters in it.  `basename` will try to interpret what's after the space as a filename suffix, and if there's more than one whitespace, you'll likely get an error from `basename`.